# which spatial server goes better with raster images stored in DB Spatialite?

Tags: spatial-database, spatialite

I would like to serve images from Spatialite as WMS services.

As far as I know:

Geoserver is compatible with vector features only -if you install the extension-, but not with spatialite BLOBs (in this case raster images).

Arcgis desktop since 10.2 supports vector layers in SQLITE, not raster images, what about ArcGIS Server, does it?

So, what other options do I have having RASTER spatialite support?

Comment: Are you really using just spatialite, or do you have the rasterlite or rasterlite2 extensions?

Comment: I am using rasterlite2 and its tools

Answer (score 1):

You can try MapServer with GDAL.

[Here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_rasterlite.html) you can find more info on RasterLite driver in GDAL.